# Difference between these implementations of LSTM Autoencoder?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pytorch

Specifically what spurred this question is the `return_sequence` argument of TensorFlow's version of an LSTM layer.

The docs say:

> *Boolean. Whether to return the last output. in the output sequence,
> or the full sequence. Default: False.*

I've seen some implementations, especially autoencoders that use this argument to strip everything but the last element in the output sequence as the output of the 'encoder' half of the autoencoder.

Below are **three** different implementations. I'd like to understand the reasons behind the differences, as the seem like very large differences but all call themselves the same thing.

#### Example 1 (TensorFlow):

This implementation strips away all outputs of the LSTM except the last element of the sequence, and then repeats that element some number of times to reconstruct the sequence:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(100, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_in,1)))
# Decoder below
model.add(RepeatVector(n_out))
model.add(LSTM(100, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1)))
```

When looking at implementations of autoencoders in PyTorch, I don't see authors doing this. Instead they use the entire output of the LSTM for the encoder (sometimes followed by a dense layer and sometimes not).

#### Example 1 (PyTorch):

This implementation trains an embedding BEFORE an LSTM layer is applied... It seems to almost defeat the idea of an LSTM based auto-encoder... The sequence is already encoded by the time it hits the LSTM layer.

```
class EncoderLSTM(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, n_layers=1, drop_prob=0):
    super(EncoderLSTM, self).__init__()
    self.hidden_size = hidden_size
    self.n_layers = n_layers

    self.embedding = nn.Embedding(input_size, hidden_size)
    self.lstm = nn.LSTM(hidden_size, hidden_size, n_layers, dropout=drop_prob, batch_first=True)

  def forward(self, inputs, hidden):
    # Embed input words
    embedded = self.embedding(inputs)
    # Pass the embedded word vectors into LSTM and return all outputs
    output, hidden = self.lstm(embedded, hidden)
    return output, hidden
```

#### Example 2 (PyTorch):

This example encoder first **expands** the input with one LSTM layer, then does its compression via a second LSTM layer with a smaller number of hidden nodes. Besides the expansion, this seems in line with this paper I found: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1607.00148.pdf

However, in this implementation's decoder, there is no final dense layer. The decoding happens through a second lstm layer that expands the encoding back to the same dimension as the original input. [See it here](https://curiousily.com/posts/time-series-anomaly-detection-using-lstm-autoencoder-with-pytorch-in-python/). This is not in line with the paper (although I don't know if the paper is authoritative or not).

```
class Encoder(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, seq_len, n_features, embedding_dim=64):
    super(Encoder, self).__init__()
    self.seq_len, self.n_features = seq_len, n_features
    self.embedding_dim, self.hidden_dim = embedding_dim, 2 * embedding_dim
    self.rnn1 = nn.LSTM(
      input_size=n_features,
      hidden_size=self.hidden_dim,
      num_layers=1,
      batch_first=True
    )
    self.rnn2 = nn.LSTM(
      input_size=self.hidden_dim,
      hidden_size=embedding_dim,
      num_layers=1,
      batch_first=True
    )
  def forward(self, x):
    x = x.reshape((1, self.seq_len, self.n_features))
    x, (_, _) = self.rnn1(x)
    x, (hidden_n, _) = self.rnn2(x)
    return hidden_n.reshape((self.n_features, self.embedding_dim))
```

#### Question:

I'm wondering about this discrepancy in implementations. The difference seems quite large. Are all of these valid ways to accomplish the same thing? Or are some of these mis-guided attempts at a "real" LSTM autoencoder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no official or correct way of designing the architecture of an LSTM based autoencoder... The only specifics the name provides is that the model should be an Autoencoder and that it should use an LSTM layer somewhere.

The implementations you found are each different and unique on their own even though they could be used for the same task.

Let's describe them:

- **TF implementation**:

  - It assumes the input has only one *channel*, meaning that each element in the sequence is *just a number* and that this is already *preprocessed*.
  - The default behaviour of the `LSTM layer` in **Keras/TF** is to output only the last output of the LSTM, you could set it to output all the output steps with the `return_sequences` parameter.
  - In this case the input data has been shrank to `(batch_size, LSTM_units)`
  - Consider that the last output of an LSTM is of course a function of the previous outputs (specifically if it is a stateful LSTM)
  - It applies a `Dense(1)` in the last layer in order to get the same shape as the input.
- **PyTorch 1**:

  - They apply an embedding to the input before it is fed to the LSTM.
  - This is standard practice and it helps for example to transform each input element to a vector form (see **word2vec** for example where in a text sequence, each word that isn't a vector is mapped into a vector space). It is only a preprocessing step so that the data has a more meaningful form.
  - This does not defeat the idea of the LSTM autoencoder, because the embedding is *applied independently* to each element of the input sequence, so it is not encoded when it enters the LSTM layer.
- **PyTorch 2**:

  - In this case the input shape is not `(seq_len, 1)` as in the first TF example, so the decoder doesn't need a dense after. The author used a number of units in the LSTM layer equal to the input shape.

In the end you choose the architecture of your model depending on the data you want to train on, specifically: the nature (text, audio, images), the input shape, the amount of data you have and so on...

Comment: I repeat, it depends on the data, on the application for the model... Too many factors. In general avery model will have some degree of success... This models can now be big and smart enough to work regardless of many factors, but at the end of the day it's the job of the engineer to define the best architecture for the application. It requires study, debug and many tries.

Comment: I guess I'm trying to go with a specific implementation because it came from a research paper and has good bench marks. It makes me nervous using people's implementations that seem to be "attempts" at turning the paper into code, but on inspection don't seem to follow the paper. Perhaps they work as well, or perhaps they don't... Do you have any thoughts on why it might be better to use the blog articles rather than trying to re-implement the paper by myself (as a relative beginner)?

Comment: Okay, that answers my question well enough I suppose. Thank you.

Comment: @rocksNwaves If you are trying to reimplement a paper, just try and do exactly what the authors did. It the paper is not clear enough for you to reimplement exactly the same architecture, then that is not a good paper.

Comment: Yeah, I think that the paper seems clear enough to code up. It's just that there is no motivation for deviating from the paper in any of these blogs/articles/tutorials. So it begs the question "Did the author change the architecture on purpose or just fail at correct implementation?".

Comment: Actually, that's my main question. Perhaps I should add an edit with that phrasing of my question. But it's probably not answerable without being in the bloggers heads.

Comment: @rocksNwaves The paper you linked seems to be of good quality as it was accepted ad ICML. I believe you can reimplement it with some effort. To answer your second question, I believe that many blog authors and that sort are not always competent enough to understand the papers they reimplement or sometimes they do not care about the exact implementation, they just want to show in general what you can achieve with some technologies.

Comment: @rocksNwaves I would not edit the question with this... the question will then become opinion based and people will flag it.

Comment: @rocksNwaves Sometimes to explain things is better to simplify and don't waste time and words with technicalities and specific implementation details, so blog authors sometimes willingly implement this papers with "errors" or "missing details".

Comment: I think people who can do that and get good results are impressive. I am the type of person who hits a wall when I see inconsistencies or missing details. I can't seem to progress until I understand completely. It's very frustrating for me, but I hope that maybe there is a benefit of gaining deeper knowledge...

Comment: @rocksNwaves you just need to keep studying and trying... with time you will gain knowledge, understanding and experience. ML is one of the hardest research fields... It seems easy because there are a lot of pertained models and great architectures for tasks related to images and such, but as soon as you exit this specific tasks and fields it becomes really hard.